# spring context jndi lookup of properties contains all props including system props, not just the one set I need

Tags: java, spring, servlets, glassfish

I'm using glassfish 3.1, spring 3.2 and jdk 1.7.

I have configured two custom JNDI resources in Glassfish. One is called 'config' and the other is called 'mappings'.  But when I reference one of them in the code, it actually has the properties for both and all system properties (catalina.base etc).  I only want the one, not all 3 sets.

I have it set so I get the properties in the spring context file:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mappingsJndi" jndi-name="mappings" resource-ref="true" />
<bean id="propertyMappings" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="propertiesArray">
            <list>
                <ref bean="mappingsJndi"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I reference it in the servlet. It's injected like this:

```
@Autowired
Properties[] propertyMappings;
```

The injection works, but it contains 3 properties objects instead of the one. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. Instead of referencing the propertyMappings bean like this:

```
@Autowired
Properties[] propertyMappings;
```

I just reference the JNDI lookup directly:

```
@Autowired
Properties mappingsJndi;
```

Comment: +1. And if you have found the solution yourself, feel free to accept your own answer.